# Doe .Net 5 have a Lookaside list implementation?

Tags: optimization, garbage-collection, .net-5

Does .NET 5 have any sort of "lookaside list" implementation that I can use?

What I need is a pre-allocated list of buffers of a fixed size that can be marked as either "available" or "in-use".  The goal is to minimize GC activity.  I've seen [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) but that seems to want items stored under a key.

The reason I ask is that my app has a mode in which it polls a high-res camera (5 million pixels per image) in a loop, asking for the current camera image.   The image gets put into a buffer (that I am currently allocating every time) and then sent to the app as an event which results in that image being displayed in UI as a XAML Image element.

Although the camera throttles this by framerate (i.e. sleeps the thread), it still eats up a lot of GC activity, according to VS diagnostic tools.  So ​I would like to at least test the effects of using a pre-allocated a list of buffers instead of allocating a new one per image.

Is there such a beast  in .NET 5 or must I roll my own in order to test?